# Rmarkdown failed to compile pdf - missing package for LaTex "\limits"

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

My `rmarkdown` is failing to compile, and the source of the error is the LaTex command `\limits`. I used the `tinytex` package to install `LaTex` packages. I've tried to track down the right `LaTex` package with no success.

The following output was generated via `html`.

```
## Compiles

$$\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(X_1 - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(X_1 - \bar{X})^2}$$

## Fails to Compile

$$\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_\limits{i = 1}^{n}(X_1 - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum_\limits{i = 1}^{n}(X_1 - \bar{X})^2}$$
```

[image]

When I try to knit to `pdf` I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. It is not `\sum_\limits{}^{}` but `\sum\limits_{}^{}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}(X_1 - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}(X_1 - \bar{X})^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea why this works when knitting `html`?

Comment: @astrofunkswag Just a guess, but I think that whatever is used to convert to html (mathjax????) might just ignore the error

Answer (score 1):

```
$$\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (X_1 - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (X_1 - \bar{X})^2}$$
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why it worked for `html`?